# What is an invariant measure under $f$?

Tags: ergodic-theory

I am reading about ergodic theory and have a question. Let $f : M \rightarrow M$ be a measurable mapping (the space where the mapping happens is not important right now). A measure $\mu$ is invariant under $f$ if
$$\mu (E) = \mu (f^{-1} (E))$$
for all measurable subsets $E \subset M.$
The author says that you can think of this condition as "the probability that a randomly chosen point is in $E$ is the same as the probability that its image is in $E$."
However, why wouldn't that mean that
$$\mu(E) = \mu (f(E))?$$

What is so special about $\mu (E) = \mu (f^{-1} (E))$? What does this mean intuitvely?

Comment: If $f$ is injective then they are the same. Otherwise the issue is that there is more than one way to describe the same set as $f(E)$.

Comment: One fact that provides some motivation: the condition $\int \phi \circ f \, d\mu = \int \phi \, d\mu$ for all $\phi \in L^1(\mu)$ holds if and only if $\mu(E) = \mu(f^{-1}(E))$ for all $\mu$-measurable $E$.

Comment: By definition $f^{-1}(E)$ is measurable, while $f(E)$ in general may not be. So this condition is the only way to define invariance for non-invertible transformation. I often think that the way measurable (or continuous) functions interact with sets is opposite to the way they interact with points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The author says that you can think of this condition as "the
> probability that a randomly chosen point is in E  is the same as the
> probability that its image is in E ." However, why wouldn't that mean
> that $\mu(E)=\mu(f(E))$?

Let's take a closer look at this. By definition
$$ x\in f^{-1}(E) \iff f(x) \in E.$$
If the mass $\mu(E)$ is the same as $\mu(f^{-1}(E))$, then "probability that randomly chosen point is in $E$ equals probability that this same points image is in $E$". This is a bit informal. Instead of looking at some hard to define random points, let's see more verbose notation of this situation:

\begin{aligned}
\mu(E) &=\mu(f^{-1}(E)) \iff\\
\mu(\{x\in X: x\in E\})& =\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)\in E\}).
\end{aligned}

It may be unnatural at first, but as you can see intuition given by this author checks out.